# Give a CFG for the complement of the set {ww| w in {a,b}* }

Tags: context-free-grammar

Give a CFG for the *complement* of the set {ww| w in {a,b}* }

I have started by realizing that all odd strings are automatically accepted, because they cannot be of form ww. So the first part of my CFG is:

S-> A | B

A-> aAa | aAb | bAa | bAb | a | b

where A handles all odd strings and B handles all even strings. I am trying to figure out what the productions for B would be, but I cant figure out how to make sure that the two halves of the string would have a character that differs in some position.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. Share some code first, and ask a specific question.